# vb.net datetime picker problems

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datetime

On another part of a program i insert the values into the database (datetime) and im trying to sum all the (countedparts) with the status (Done) within a certain day using 1 datetime picker.

my datebase looks like so:

```
  countedparts  status  startdate
  -----------------------------------------
  34            Done     19/09/2014 04:34:54
  134           Done     19/09/2014 06:42:42
  21            Done     19/09/2014 10:43:26
```

my query is below:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(countedparts) FROM sqlccmlinestatus WHERE status = 'Done' and startdate = '" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date  & "'"
            Done.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

For some reason its not working, i think its due to the date time picker being e.g. 19/09/2014 00:00:00 and im trying to get records between 19/09/2014 00:00:00 and 19/09/2014 23:59:59.

Any idea's would be great.

Many Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Use sql-parameters and you don't need to care about localization issues or -more important- sql-injection. Apart from that you have to use `startdate >= @startdata  AND startdate < @enddata` where `@enddata` is the `startDate.AddDays(1)`.

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: First step: change your `WHERE` condition as suggested by Tim. Second step: Use parameters instead of string concatenation as suggested by Tim. Third step: Bind the values to those parameters with i.e. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`